# Regresstion Tree in R

Tags: profiling, regression

I'am writing CART in R from scratch and I'm almost done. Nevertheless I have problem with efficiency: bottleneck of my code is procedure below.

```
best_split2 <- function(dataset){
sse2 <- matrix(nrow=dim(dataset)[1], ncol=length((dataset))-1)
for(i in 1:(length(dataset)-1)){
    for(l in 1:dim(dataset)[[1]]){
        splits <- split_test3(dataset[[i]][l], i, dataset)
        sse2[l,][i] <- cost_func3(splits)
    }
}
sse_min2 <- min(sse2)
mins <- which(sse2 == sse_min2, arr.ind = TRUE)[1,]
index1 <- unname(mins[2])
index2 <- unname(mins[1])
split_val2 <- dataset[[index1]][index2]
splits2 <- split_test3(split_val2, index1, dataset)
return(list(sse = sse_min2, index = index2, split_val = split_val2, splits = splits2, left = NULL, right = NULL))
```

}

In best_split2 I'am searching the best split variable in dataset. Take into account that split_test3 and cost_func3 functions are written optimally and they are extremely fast. 
Do you have any tips how to optimise this function?

Thank you!